# ASP.NET, Windows Authentication and querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Scenario:
A website in ASP.NET C# on windows server 2012 with sqlserver 2014. User Authentication by Windows Authentication set in the web.config as follow:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
        <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

The website is for users that have a local account in the server. No active directory. No under the same domain.

When an user opens a page of the website as follow

```
http://<mydomain>/default.aspx
```

Windows Authentication is required: a Windows Dialog Box Appears. User inserts his own username and password.
If the credentials are valid, user is authenticathed, and the page

```
http://<mydomain>/default.aspx
```

is loaded. Authentication is no more required for the current session (until the user closes the browser or restarts the pc).

Suppose that a user is not authenticated on the website, and he wants to open the url as follow

```
http://<mydomain>/default.aspx?id=1
```

Note the query string

```
id=1
```

is used by the page default.aspx to load data -for example- from a database.

Since the user is not authenticated, the Windows Dialog Box requires username and password.
User inserts the right credential and he is authenticated.
The page

```
http://<mydomain>/default.aspx
```

is loaded.

Note the query string

```
id=1
```

is missing

Users expects to open the link as follow

```
http://<mydomain>/default.aspx?id=1
```

But after the Authentication the page

```
http://<mydomain>/default.aspx
```

is loaded. Query string missing. So the user has to insert in the browser the url again

```
http://<mydomain>/default.aspx?id=1
```

The web.config file as follow

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>

    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
            <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>   

    <membership>
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
        <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
        <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="120" />
</system.web>
```

Is it possible to maintain the query string after authentication in the url? Is there such a protection in IIS that not consider query string before authentication?

Thanks

Comment: Does your web.config have <authentication mode="Windows"/>
<authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>

Comment: Are you sure you're using "Windows Authentication" as set in IIS / Website / Authentication - and all other options disabled?  Or are you using Forms Login but authenticated against active directory?   Are you already in a domain and does your account have access to the website?  What does the "insert the Windows Credential" dialog/process/inputs actually look like?  With Windows Authentication, you should not get prompted if you have access.

Comment: Just added a web.config file part in the question, not using Forms Login, neither active directory. Accounts used are users of the server, not part of a domain. When you open the page, a Windows Dialog Box appears requiring username e password. After the authentication, you can access all the pages of the website.

Comment: It's a website on IIS in ASP.NET c# used  to manage our customers backend.(Windows Server 2012, with Sql Server 2014).

Example: When a customer open a ticket for a support request, an email is sent to the support team containing a link like this 'http://<mydomain>/ticket.aspx?id=345'
If you are authenticated, the webpage ticket.aspx show the request no 345 thanks to the query string. If you are not autheticated, a Windows Dialog Box appears. After the authentication, you are on
the page 'http://<mydomain>/ticket.aspx' NOT 'http://<mydomain>/ticket.aspx?id=345'  as the link.

Answer (score -1):

In your code behind at the login page (or wherever you put the login form on), try this:

```
// Login Button Click Event
        protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //verify user's credential 
            // if it is correct then 
            // do whatever you want, create a session, cookie etc..., then redirect user:     
                        string strRedirect;
                        strRedirect = Request["ReturnUrl"];
                        if (strRedirect == null) strRedirect = "/"; // if there isn't any query string then redirect user to default page
                        Response.Redirect(strRedirect, true);
            // else display wrong username/password message...
        }
```

Comment: Using Windows Authentiation, not Forms Login.
For the login a Windows Dialog Box appears requiring credentials.
There is not a login form.

Comment: This code is extremely susceptible to [Open Redirect Attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574764/how-to-prevent-open-redirection-attacks) and should *never* be used as is.