# How to prevent to URL redirection attacks in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, security, url, iis-7

I have a ASP.NET application, where there is a page redirect.

Header looks like

```
GET         
/website/module/ABC.aspx?session="UserLogin|";"Filename|";"Parameters|"
Cookie: Language=; ASPSESSIONIDCURQTBBQ=MMMMMMJYYYYGGDESSJOOMAOLD;
ASP.NET_SessionId=09or5lreee0ezyjxc5x1ceroroem     
Host: website   
Connection: Keep-alive   
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate   
User-Agent: -----
Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.21   
Accept: */*
```

Code that do redirect is

```
var URL= '/website/module/ABC.aspx? session="UserLogin|";"Filename|";"Parameters|"'; 
Response.Redirect(URL);
```

So it is vulnerable to attacker.
How to prevent such attack?

Details on : [URL Redirection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent open redirection attacks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574764/how-to-prevent-open-redirection-attacks)

Comment: @शेखर, checked your link, but my problem is different

Comment: `So it is vulnerable to attacker` - how do you figure? What is your reasoning?

Comment: @SilverlightFox There are many security audit firm and tool available in market, check one  http://www.acunetix.com/

Comment: I know, but you haven't explained that in your question. It needs more details such as a code example at least.

Comment: @SilverlightFox, I have simple code here as                                                 var URL= '/website/module/ABC.aspxsession="UserLogin|";"Filename|";"Parameters|"';                                                                                                                   Response.Redirect(URL);

Comment: Add it to your question by using the [edit] button.

Comment: Your code appears to be invalid. Single quotes are used for character delimiters, not strings.